# A uniform scalar quantizer

Tags: communication, signal

I have a uniform scalar quantizer with M=4 levels of quantization, and a natural mapping from levels to bits of the `01000110111110` Frame. Is it possible that this frame is a suitable for the signal \$x(t)=\sin(t)\$?

I am not sure how approach this, in the class we didn't practice this stuff.

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more context for this question, because I have no idea what you're talking about. Is this an electronics question or a math question?

Comment: NOt sure what's up with the down votes, I suspect people are revealing their ignorance again.  This is very clearly in the realm of EE and in particular communications theory pertaining to the same area where trellis decoding, Viterbi decoding and most modern modulation schemes lie like ODFM etc..  I do agree that the OP should fill in more background if he expects an answer.  Further more since it's homework most people will require that show more work or effort.  SO it may deserve a close vote to clean up but DV?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- four levels of quantization means how many bits in a sample?
- what might a "natural mapping" be? (Would a scrambled sequence of codes like 10, 01, 11, 00 be a natural mapping for increasing levels?)
- what if we chop the frame into samples?